# В selenium нет метода find_element_by_id

Tags: python, selenium

Всех приветствую.
Код следующий:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://suninjuly.github.io/simple_form_find_task.html")
button = browser.find_element_by_id("submit")
```

Данный кусок скопирован из какой-то статьи по типу [раз](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find_element_by_partial_link_text-driver-method-selenium-python/), [два](https://stepik.org/lesson/267247/step/2).
В чём суть: при поиске элементов я всегда использовал подобные конструкции через `By`:

```
el = driver.find_element(By.ID, "my_id")
```

Но недавно я наткнулся на несколько страниц (упомянул выше), на которых рассматривались аналоги подходу через `By.ID` (Самый первый кусок).
Там несколько функций по типу `find_element_by_css_selector`, `find_element_by_name` и т.д.    Выглядит заманчиво, но при попытке попробовать я наткнулся на ту самую ошибку.

```
button = browser.find_element_by_id("submit")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'
```

Я проверил версию Selenium'а, но там всё в порядке (на данный момент это актуальная на [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)):

```
selenium           4.15.2
```

При этом в официальной [документации](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/) я не нашёл такого сахара.
Вопрос: почему это не работает?

Comment: ``find_element_by_...`` уже не существует. Нужно пользоваться ``find_element(By.ID, )`` и т.д. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355469/why-use-find-elementby-instead-of-find-element-by